# Big difference in execution time between AnyCpu and x86

Tags: c#, wpf, benchmarking, execution-time, target-platform

When I was using one of my libraries I found something strange! I have a class library that is responsible for reading a specific file type. And it's doing its job well.

I used the `Read` method of a class in this class library project in two different projects (WPF & Console).

**What I found:** Reading an 40MB file in `WPF Application` using the class library takes **17min**. But reading the same file using the `Console Application` takes **1min**.

Here is the same code that I'm using in two different projects.

```
DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;                             
var geometris = MyLibrary.Read(fileName);
TimeSpan dt1 = DateTime.Now - t1;       //dt1: 17min for WPF
                                        //dt1:  1min for Console
```

**What I tried:** I found that the `Console Application`'s Platform target is x86 and the `WPF Application`'s target platform is AnyCpu. So I changed the `WPF`'s target platform to x86 and run it again. This time the execution time was **3min**  (14min faster)

**Question:** Anyone knows *how* changing the target platform has such influence? And still I don't know why the WPF App. is 2 min slower than Console when calling the same method with the same input from my library?

Comment: Its better if you use [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) for measuring executing time. Are you building in Release mode or Debug mode for the projects ?

Comment: Theres something wrong in your `What I tried section`. Do you changed WPF app to x86 plattform, maybe?

Comment: @Habib Actually I used Stopwatch but here I used `DateTime` because it needs less lines of code. I'm building in Debug mode

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad, build in release mode and see if you get the difference

Comment: @Habib I'm going to check...

Comment: Can we assume you have a 64-bit OS? The runtime has different JIT compilers for x64 and x86.

Comment: @mikez I have 64-bit OS.

Comment: @Habib I did it in release mode. And was difference.

Answer (score 2):

In my practice, there wasn't much difference between x86 and x64 performance. In your case the reason might be in different RAM usage; in x64 mode, all object references take up twice as much RAM.

Comment: Thanks. What about the 2min difference between WPF and Console application (when both are in x86 mode)?

Comment: @Hossein Narimani Rad, WPF apps consume more RAM, than console apps. But this might have another reason as well. You need to test your app on another PC with bigger amount of RAM.

Comment: @Hossein Narimani Rad, you can also try to run your program without debugging. (executing with debugger can result in very different performance)